# Selenium.getText() problem

Tags: java, selenium

Hope someone can help me here?

Having an issue getting text that's located inside a tag but After another tag...

```
<li><b>**Duration Held:**</b> 5 Years </li>
```

I need to return the "5 Years" part of the Text but selenium.getText() returns the whole `<li>` contents, which is correct, but I need the text after the `</b>` tag but can't figure out a way to achieve this task?

Has anyone come across this type of scenario, if so, what was done to get the text after a `</b>` but still inside the `<li>` tag ???

I'm stumped, Any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using selenium IDE or selenium RC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use regex to extract what you want. such as;

```
            String st = selenium.getText();
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("</b>([^<]+)</li>");
        Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(st);
        if (matcher.matches())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: @Joseph Remember to only compile the pattern once as it is expensive